# The last item is being pushed to Array (Javascript)

Tags: javascript

Hi I have below code in my project. The problem is the last item is being pushed to an array instead of each item.

JS Function

---

```js
function getArrayObjForKeys(keys, source, desiredKeys) {
  let arrayObj = [],
    obj = {};
  source.forEach(function(val, ind) {
    keys.forEach(function(v, i) {
      (function(v) {
        if (val.hasOwnProperty(v)) {
          let desKey = desiredKeys[i];
          obj[desKey] = val[v];
        }
      }).call(this, v);
    });
    arrayObj.push(obj);
  });
  return arrayObj;
}

// Invoking function as below
// **************************

var source = [{
  'country': 'USA',
  'descr': 'United States'
}, {
  'country': 'UK',
  'descr': 'United Kingdom'
}];
var countryList = getArrayObjForKeys(['country', 'descr'], source, ['value', 'label']);
console.info(countryList);
```

Desired Output

---

```
[{'value':'USA','label':'United States'},{'value':'UK','label':'United Kingdom'}]
```

Plunker

---

https://next.plnkr.co/edit/3SKbaJo9r5QX8hex?open=lib%2Fscript.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that you're referring to the same `obj` in memory and thus modifying both objects. A quick fix to this is to move your object declaration into the `foreach` loop, so you have your own unique reference to each object (not the same).

See working example below:

```js
function getArrayObjForKeys(keys, source, desiredKeys) {
  let arrayObj = []
  
  source.forEach(function(val, ind) {
    let obj = {}; /* Move into foreach */
    keys.forEach(function(v, i) {
      (function(v) {
        if (val.hasOwnProperty(v)) {
          let desKey = desiredKeys[i];
          obj[desKey] = val[v];
        }
      }).call(this, v);
    });
    arrayObj.push(obj);
  });
  return arrayObj;
}


var source = [{
  'country': 'USA',
  'descr': 'United States'
}, {
  'country': 'UK',
  'descr': 'United Kingdom'
}];

var countryList = getArrayObjForKeys(['country', 'descr'], source, ['value', 'label']);
console.info(countryList);
```

Comment: @ukb awesome! no worries :)

Answer (score 1):

You can map the source to the desired output using reduce to reduce the keys, desiredKeys and object to a new object:

```js
function getArrayObjForKeys(keys, source, desiredKeys) {
    return source.map(function(obj) {
        return keys.reduce(function(result, key, index) {
            result[desiredKeys[index]] = obj[key];
            return result;
        }, {});
    });
}

var source = [{ country: 'USA', descr: 'United States' }, { country: 'UK', descr: 'United Kingdom' }];
var countryList = getArrayObjForKeys(['country', 'descr'], source, ['value', 'label']);
console.info(countryList);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to do it, using `reduce`, `Object.entries` and `map`:

```js
function getArrayObjForKeys(keys, source, desiredKeys) {
  return source.map(obj => Object.entries(obj).reduce((accum, [key, val]) => {
    const keyIdx = keys.indexOf(key);
    accum[desiredKeys[keyIdx]] = val;
    return accum;
  }, {}));
}

const source = [
  { 'country': 'USA', 'descr': 'United States' },
  { 'country': 'UK', 'descr': 'United Kingdom' }
];

const countryList = getArrayObjForKeys(['country', 'descr'], source, ['value', 'label']);

console.info(countryList);
```

Comment: Object.entries is not to be guaranteed to come in any particular order so you should not use it in this way.

Comment: Well, in this case it is not a problem since we are outputting an object from the reduce function, and keys are not guaranteed to be ordered in an object either. So the input is unordered, you are right, but the output does not rely on the input being ordered.

Answer (score 0):

A more concise alternative, using ES6 (and provided both input arrays always have the same length) would be :

```js
const getArrayObjForKeys = (keys, source, desiredKeys) => source.map( obj => {
 let output = {};
 keys.forEach( (key,i) => output[desiredKeys[i]] = obj[keys[i]]);
 return output;
})
 

const source = [{'country':'USA','descr':'United States'},{'country':'UK','descr':'United Kingdom'}],
   countryList = getArrayObjForKeys(['country','descr'], source, ['value','label']);

console.info(countryList);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
getArrayObjForKeys(keys,source,desiredKeys){
    let arrayObj=[];
    source.forEach(function(val,ind){
    let obj={};
        keys.forEach(function(v,i){
          (function(v){
            if(val.hasOwnProperty(v)){
              let desKey = desiredKeys[i];
              obj[desKey] = val[v];
            }
          }).call(this, v);
        });
        arrayObj.push(obj);
    });
    return arrayObj;
  }
```

Update the obj variable inside the foreach loop.

Issue is with obj variable

Answer (score 0):

If you want less code, here's a more specific function.

```js
function easy(obj) {
  return obj = obj.map(obj => {
    return {"value": obj.country, "lable": obj.descr};
  });
}

obj = [{
  "country": "USA",
  "descr": "United States"
}, {
  "country": "UK",
  "descr": "United Kingdom"
}];

obj = easy(obj);

console.log(obj);
```